# What does it mean to send a resolution "over, under the rule"?

Tags: united-states, senate, legislative-process

This is in the [congressional record](https://www.congress.gov/114/crec/2015/01/06/CREC-2015-01-06-pt1-PgS22-2.pdf) from yesterday:

> RESOLUTION OVER, UNDER THE RULE—S. RES. 18
> Mr. MCCONNELL. Mr. President, I have a resolution at the desk.
> The PRESIDENT pro tempore. The clerk will report the resolution by title.
> The assistant legislative clerk read as follows:
> A resolution (S. Res. 18) making majority party appointments for the 114th Congress.
> Mr. MCCONNELL. I ask for its immediate consideration, and to send the
> resolution over, under the rule, and I object to my own request.
> The PRESIDENT pro tempore. Objection is heard.
> The resolution will go over, under the rule.

What does it mean to send a resolution "over, under the rule" and what purpose does the requester objecting to his own request serve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question, it appears this is simply a procedural tactic used to delay the consideration of a resolution until the next legislative day. The "rule" refers to [Senate Rule XIV](https://www.rules.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/CDOC-113sdoc18.pdf#page=15) Paragraph 6, which states:

> All other resolutions shall lie over one day for consideration, if not referred, unless by unanimous consent the Senate shall otherwise direct. **When objection is heard to the immediate consideration of a resolution or motion when it is submitted, it shall be placed on the Calendar under the heading of "Resolutions and Motions over, under the Rule," to be laid before the Senate on the next legislative day** when there is no further morning business but before the close of morning business and before the termination of the morning hour.

Comment: Also see: http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-RIDDICK-1992/pdf/GPO-RIDDICK-1992-93.pdf.  My best guess is that this is not used for the purpose of delaying consideration, but instead to preempt the opposition from arbitrarily raising an objection and thus forcing the delay.  Better to delay everything yourself than have some things delayed unexpectedly.

Comment: This is also useful - it describes various ways that business can come before the Senate - http://www.senate.gov/CRSReports/crs-publish.cfm?pid=%26*2%3C4RLW%3D%0A